# Some special characters are not shown

Tags: c#, encoding

I'm working with a csv that contains some accented words, it's already coming in symbol form ... how can I fix this problem

```
input:
BRANDï¿½O

expected:
BRANDÃO
```

I am using this code:

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
var bytes = encoding.GetBytes("BRANDï¿½O");
string out = encoding.GetString(bytes);
```

the out is:

```
BRAND?O
```

Comment: Did you try utf-8

Comment: Yes, but still same...

Comment: Have u tried to trim and remove any extra space

Comment: Yes,I tried some other coding, but without result